# acts_as_taggable_on: how to optimize the query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I use `acts_as_taggable_on` in my current Rails project. On one overview page i am displaying an index of objects with their associated tags. I use the following code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :categories
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end

# in the view
<% @projects.each do |p| %>
   <%= p.name %>
   <% p.category_list.each do |t| %>
     <%= t %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This all works as expected. However, if i am displaying 20 projects, `acts_as_taggable_on` is firing 20 queries to fetch the associated tags.

How can I include the loading of the tags in the original db query?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

@projects = Project.includes(:categories).all

Comment: that's it thanks. I tried this, but it didn't work because i was using  `category_list` to display the tags. It works if you just use `Project.categories`.

Comment: just ran into this myself, I used '.includes' and instead of using 'category_list' I used something like categories.map{|cat| cat.name} in the view, and still saw a huge performance boost.

Comment: If you are using multiple `acts_as_taggable_on` attributes on the same model, you also need to include all of them for this work. EX: `Project.includes(:categories, :topics).all`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

Post.includes(:tags).all

and then:

post.tags.collect { |t| t.name }

Comment: This is the one that improved the performance with rails serializers!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jan Drewniak, huge performance boosted with

```
Download.includes(:tags).all
```

and in views:

```
download.tags.map {|t| link_to t, t.name}.join(', ')
```

But still too slow.

Any other idea?

Comment: Do you have created the appropriate indexes?

Comment: What you mean? Where I can find the appropriate indexes to create?

Comment: Usually the ones created by default https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/tree/master/db/migrate are enough. Do these exist in your project? You might want to check using ActiveRecords explain, i. e execute `download.tags.explain` and see if an index is used.